# How to determine whether an integral is convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

For this question, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, can anyone please help me out?

Determine whether the following integral is convergent or divergent.

$$\int_5^6 \frac 1 {(x-3)\sqrt {x-5}} \, dx$$

$$ \frac{1}{(x-3)\sqrt {x-5}}\le \frac{1}{x-3}$$

Since $\int_5^6 \frac 1 {x-3} \,dx$ converges, $\int_5^6 \frac 1 {(x-3)\sqrt {x-5}} \, dx$ must also converge.

Comment: So then how would we go about that then?

Comment: That doesn't work: The problematic point is the behavior of $\sqrt{x-5},$ not of $x-3. \qquad$

Comment: @AndrewLi : A mere discontinuity will not cause any difficulty; rather the issue is the vertical asymptote. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is not valid. Rather, 
\begin{align*}
0<\dfrac{1}{(x-3)\sqrt{x-5}}<\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x-5}},~~~~x\in(5,6],
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\int_{5}^{6}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}&=\lim_{\eta\rightarrow 5^{+}}\int_{\eta}^{6}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}dx\\
&=\lim_{\eta\rightarrow 5^{+}}2\sqrt{x-5}\bigg|_{\eta}^{6}\\
&=\lim_{\eta\rightarrow 5^{+}}\left(2-2\sqrt{\eta-5}\right)\\
&=2\\
&<\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: Why did you multiply the root by two?

Comment: For $x\in(5,6]$, then $x-3>2$, and so $\dfrac{1}{x-3}<\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Where did the 1 over two go in the integration?

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: You forgot the constant in your integration at the beginning?

Comment: You just went straight to integrating 1 over root of x-5

Comment: Okay, but that does not affect the convergence.

Comment: Ok, so when I integrate it I just take the constant into consideration and show the 1 over two times the root of x-5 converges, so the whole thing converges?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: So in general when we  are determining whether the integral converges or diverges for an integral where a discontinuity occurs, we always compare it to the integral at which the discontinuity occurs at?

Comment: Because in this question there is only one discontinuity, so this strategy goes through. If there were multiple discontinuities, it is hard to tell a general strategy.

Comment: If the numerator had an x-7 and/or 3x+5, would that affect the result of this question?

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality does not hold because the left handside is unbounded but the right handside is bounded on the interval $[5,6]$.

Actually you have
$ \frac{1}{(x-3)\sqrt {x-5}}$ $\le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-5}}$
Then substitute $y=x-5$. Now, you obtain
$$I\leq \int_5^6 \dfrac{dx}{2\sqrt{x-5}}=\frac12\int_0^1\dfrac{dy}{y^{1/2}}$$

Here the right hand side converges by the p-test, so it implies the convergence of your original integral $I$.

Comment: If the numerator had an x-7 and/or 3x+5, would that affect the result of this question?

Comment: @dg123 no, again the method would be to write your integrand as $\dfrac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x-5}}$ where f(x) is well-defined on your compact interval and therefore obtain some maximum value $M$. And again you obtain $I\leq M\int_5^6\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x-5}}$ so that you have to proceed with a similar substitution.

Comment: So pretty much, it'd be the same answer?

Comment: @dg123 yes. On the contrary, if you multiply with $f(x)$ having singularities on $[5,6]$ there might be some issues: Take $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x-a}$, where are $a\in \{5,6\}$. Now the integral diverges by the p-test.